# Where can I find Help Your Neighbor?

Tags: identify-this-game

I played a card and dice game called “Help Your Neighbor” several years ago. When the player rolled the dice, he/she could discard the number that matched the sum of the dice.

Is a complete set of rules available? I saw rules posted here but can no longer find them.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know that game, but a quick look into a search engine gave this link:

https://creatingmaryshome.com/help-your-neighbor-a-game/

the article includes the rules, not sure if they what you are searching for, feel free to update this answer to include the details yourself

Comment: Thank you Joe W. This is it and is exactly what I needed!! Thanks!!

Answer (score -2):

The game is available for purchase at this link: https://www.thegamecrafter.com/games/help-your-neighbor1